# How many $7$ digit numbers can be formed from $1,2$ and $3$, s.t each of them was used atleast twice

Tags: combinatorics

> Q:How many $7$ digit numbers can be formed  from $1,2$ and $3$, s.t
>   each of them was used atleast twice

I've tried using inclusion/exlusion method, but that gave me lots of cases.

I used to choose $\binom{7}{2}$ as 1, another $\binom{5}{2}$ as 2, and the other $\binom{3}{2}$ as 3. For the last remaining digit I have 3 choices. So I've got $\binom{7}{2}*\binom{5}{2}*\binom{3}{2}*3=1890$.

But the program I made in c++, counted them $630$, which is $\binom{7}{2}*\binom{5}{2}*\binom{3}{2}$.

What's the problem that I cant see here, what did I overcounted there?

Comment: With the binomial coefficients you are counting places, with the last factor you are counting possibilities.

Comment: So I'm not allowed to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three possible sets: $ 1122333, 1122233, 1112233$. Each of these has $\dfrac{7!}{3!2!2!}$ arrangements. So your total is $\dfrac{3\cdot 7!}{3!2!2!}=\dfrac{7!}{2!2!2!} =\dfrac{7!}{8} = 630$

Your attempt overcounts where the last digit goes compared to those of the same value - for example, if you have chosen (up to the last digit) $123X321$, and then choose say $3$  for that last place, that is the same as $12X3321$ or $1233X21$ and then choosing  a final $3$.

Comment: (+1) for the method, which I've forgot. Can you give an example of where it overcounts

Comment: @shcolf added to the answer